# If my question is a duplicate but there is no answer to the original question, what should I do?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

I am having a problem with access and I noticed that this question ( [Access Filter VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645971/access-filter-vba) ) is identical to the one I want to ask.

However there is no suitable answer for this question. Should I make another question and reference to the original?

Comment: See [this faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/176080) :-)

Comment: I do not have enough rep to post a bounty and the question is not my own to edit. I dont think this really answers my question.

Comment: Anyone can edit any contribution (with peer approval) - you could edit that post to include things you have tried.

Comment: I have tried to edit the question as you have advised so hopefully it gets noticed.

Comment: I have added a bounty to the question to bring it attention.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thanks you, I appreciate that.

Comment: I "Improved" (you'll still get the +2 rep) the question in the suggested edit queue to fix a little terminology and link back here so it should find it's way to the front page shortly.

Comment: [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. This is what the [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-workx) system is for. As I have done with the question you link, you can start a bounty to bring attention to the answer.
2. If you don't have sufficient reputation, then you could possibly post a link to the question in a related [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) room.
3. If all else fails, and the old question STILL doesn't contain a working answer after all of this, then you can re-ask the question. While it does have the chance of getting closed, you could probably plead to have it re-opened if you need to.

Comment: This is what I expected, I just have to hope the community picks this one up. Accepting Answer

Comment: @VBwhatnow you are welcome, just remember to up-vote the answer that you think works, so that I can give it the bounty.

Comment: You can also edit the original question to add extra details if necessary, which also bumps the question

Comment: If you end up re-asking the question, it also helps to acknowledge that there's an existing question and say why that previous question is different or hasn't solved your problem.